# Docker Couchbase Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8091: Connection refused

Tags: docker, couchbase

I am running couchbase on docker. My machine: ubuntu 16.04

I've a Couchbase image. I'm running some curl commands to configure the Couchbase server and to create an admin user. Problem is, curl fails with error message Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8091: Connection refused. netstat does not show that port 8091 on the localhost is listening. those work! What am I missing?

I copy out this script : 
https://github.com/madhur/couchbase-docker/blob/master/couchbase/configure-node.sh

here is my Dockerfile all content:

> FROM couchbase:community-4.0.0
>
> COPY configure-node.sh /opt/couchbase
>
> CMD ["/opt/couchbase/configure-node.sh"]

I changed Docker file From line like that:
FROM couchbase/server

Then the connection error is finished. then I see this error:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/23065389/

I didn't understand why and How can I fix it?

Comment: you should provide more information about the content of your dockerfile so people can troubleshoot your problem.

Comment: Are you forwarding the ports using `-p`? Complete instructions at https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/couchbase/.

Comment: I added Dockerfile content to question. Should I forward the ports? I am setting ports in docker-compose.yml only.

Comment: Yes, container ports need to be forwarded to host port. You can also follow the instructions at https://github.com/arun-gupta/docker-images/tree/master/couchbase

Comment: Sorry I think we are forwarding ports in docker-compose.yml:
       **ports:
            - "8091-8093:8091-8093"
            - "11210:11210"**

Comment: are you starting the containers using `docker-compose up -d`?

Comment: I am using `docker-compose up -d couchbase-db`

Comment: https://github.com/madhur/couchbase-docker/blob/master/couchbase/configure-node.sh is awfully similar to https://github.com/arun-gupta/docker-images/blob/master/couchbase/configure-node.sh. However the Dockerfile is using `couchbase:community-3.1.3`. Is that that version you want? I never tested the script with that Couchbase version.

Comment: Can you try https://github.com/arun-gupta/docker-images/blob/master/couchbase/docker-compose.yml and see if it works?

Comment: I changed Docker file like that: than it works know. I think last two lines solved the problem.

**FROM couchbase/server      
    
     COPY configure-node.sh /opt/couchbase

     CMD ["/opt/couchbase/configure-node.sh"]

     ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
     CMD ["couchbase-server"]**

Comment: My application is running now, thank you.  But I set username and password in script file above. When I go localhost:8091 username: Administrator and password : password is not working. Why it is not setted like in configure-node.sh?

Comment: Can you share your `configure-node.sh`?

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version you should not face that issue, it's pretty seamless.

```
"docker run -d --name mycouchdb -p 8091-8094:8091-8094 -p 11210:11210 couchbase"
```

will create a container with name mycouchdb and if you run `docker logs mycouchdb` then you should see that in order to access the DB URL, its on http://:8091